# Get time diff in tenths of seconds

Tags: bash, shell

Just trying to keep track of the build time for a bash script, to the 1/10th of a second

I am looking for something like:

```
    START_TIME=$(date)
    sleep 5;
    END_TIME=$(date)-${START_TIME};
```

and round it to a tenth of a second.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you attempted anything? You could just get the time before and after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use date with nanosecond and truncate to one char

```
#!/bin/bash

START=$(date "+%s%1N")
sleep 2
END=$(date "+%s%1N")

echo "The difference is $((END-START))"
```

Comment: `%N` is nanoseconds, the 1 truncates to 1 char.

Comment: Do you need the surrounding quotes?

Comment: Nope, you can if you want though.